# Select from nested entity framework entity

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 4.3.

I have a user entity named Lender - a lender has many lending Tiers. There are many other entities linked to lender but for or the purpose of clarity, I'll keep the structure simple.

What I need to do is return a lender but only with a single matched Tier based on some criteria, in other words a flattened structure for Tier.

I'm unsure as to how to do this in a single statement - can anyone help?

Comment: Can you elaborate? an example of input/output would clarify your question.

Comment: Also, what does your query look like right now, where are you having problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of your "*flattened structure for Tier*" is a bit dark to me but perhaps you are looking for a projection like the following one:

```
var lenderWithTier = context.Lenders
    .Where(l => l.Something == something) // lender filter
    .Select(l => new
    {
        Lender = l,
        Tier = l.Tiers
            .Where(t => t.SomethingElse == somethingElse) // tier filter
            .FirstOrDefault() // only one tier
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

`lenderWithTier` is an anonymous object that has a `lenderWithTier.Lender` property and a `lenderWithTier.Tier` property which is a single `Tier` object (or `null` if none of the tiers related to the lender matches the tier filter).

Comment: Apologies for the vagueness in the question - I just didn't know how to phrase is well. You have understood the requirement perfectlly - this is what I need to do.